# Ordered array implementation of Symbol Table

Tags: c, dictionary, data-structures, associative-array, symbol-table

Ordered array representation with binary search  for Symbol table implementation, can be

```
 char *key[20];
   int val[20];
```

or

```
  typedef struct {
        char *key,
         int value
    }Entry;
    Entry array[20];
```

---

where `key` is always inserted to maintain ordered array, in either implementation

1)

From `insert` & `search` performance perspective, which is the better representation?

2)

Related question about terminology:

From representation aspect, how different are *Symbol table*, *associative array* & *Dictionary*, from each other?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13239607/parallel-array-or-array-of-structures

Comment: @WillisBlackburn Your linked query is talking about CPU performance

Comment: It's talking about parallel arrays vs. arrays of structs and the performance implications of using one or the other. Of course it's going to be about insert and search performance; what else do you do with a collection, except maybe delete?

Comment: Or maybe iterate. :-)

Comment: @WillisBlackburn What about Access? Accessing an array is `O(1)`, and the other things like insertion and deletion are `O(n)`.

Comment: He has arrays in both cases though.

Comment: @Willisblackburn rather say ordered arrays in both cases

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parallel array or array of structures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13239607/parallel-array-or-array-of-structures)